# pyautogui.screenshot region is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, pyautogui

When I try to capture a video screenshot of my screen in a region suddenly the .avi output file becomes a 7kb. 
The is no error, so I do not know how to fix this
The output video is fine before selecting the region.
how can i fix this problem?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyautogui
# display screen resolution, get it from your OS settings
import tkinter as tk

from PIL.Image import Image

root = tk.Tk()
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
SCREEN_SIZE = (screen_width, screen_height)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID")
# create the video write object
out = cv2.VideoWriter("output.avi", fourcc, 20.0, (SCREEN_SIZE))
while True:
    # make a screenshot

    img = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(350, 800, 500, 150))
    # convert these pixels to a proper numpy array to work with OpenCV
    frame = np.array(img)
    # convert colors from BGR to RGB
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    # write the frame
    out.write(frame)
    # show the frame
    cv2.imshow("screenshot", frame)
    # if the user clicks q, it exits
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
        break

# make sure everything is closed when exited
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
out.release()
```

Comment: You set the output VideoWriter size to be the full size of the screen, but when you later write it, you only pass a smaller image corresponding to the ROI.

Comment: can you please tell me what should be put instead? I tried (500,150) but it doesnt work as well

Comment: Try printing `frame.shape` just before you write the video file.

Comment: Thank you very much it is: (150, 500, 3)

Comment: but as I said out = cv2.VideoWriter("output.avi", fourcc, 20.0, (150,500)) or out = cv2.VideoWriter("output.avi", fourcc, 20.0, (500,150)) gives me the same result of 6kb output

Comment: You need to pay attention to ordering. Numpy uses height x width in `frame.shape` whereas `videoWriter()` probably uses width x height. I'm just saying you need to check.

Comment: thank you very much I should have also changed 20.0 to 8.0